# How to call a function from a reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, reverse-proxy

My application calls a certain a function that takes a keyword which is passed to two API's query string.
But due to cors problem, I decided to use a reverse proxy and then an Express server route.

I then imported the function into my express server and passed the search term in by using REgex to parse keyword into the function as
`req.params.endpoint`
The function is called but the but the api isn't fetched, I get undefined. But if I send in empty strings, it works, but thats obviously not what I want.

I send the search Term through the browser like so `http://localhost:5000/searchTerm`

The function is called like so...

````
app.get(':endpoint([\\/\\w\\ ]*)', async (req, res) =>{
      let search = req.params.endpoint
      let str = search.split('/')[1]
      const call = await callFetch(search) // callFetch is the imported function 
      res.send(call)
    
})```

The callFetch function uses promise.all to resolve both api calls

```function callFetch(a){ 
       searchTerm = a
       console.log('callfetch is getting ', searchTerm) 
       const promises = [Fetch(https://firstapinet.com/search.php?search=${searchTerm}),
       Fetch(https://secondapinet.com/search.php?search=${searchTerm})]
       Promise.all(promises)
        .then(values => console.log(values))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}```

My Fetch function


```async function Fetch(url){
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const result = await response.text()
      return result;
   }```

I always get an array of undefined except when I send in an empty string. What can I do please?
Is there another way of getting my search term to the fetch function to eliminate the cors problem?
````

Comment: No return in `callFetch`?

Comment: I used console.log. Still testing it. The logged result is what I'm looking at. All I get is an array of undefined.